# Fire A trigger if a case is viewed by the Owner

Tags: apex, trigger, case

My requirement is to set a case into a particular status if the case is viewed.
There is a field that I can use which is lastvieweddate though I tried it but it seems not to work.

My code is below.

```
if(myCaseRec.viewed_by_Handler__c = FALSE && myCaseRec.LastViewedDate == system.now() && myCaseRec.OwnerId == UserInfo.getUserId()){ 
   myCaseRec.viewed_by_Handler__c = TRUE;
   myCaseRec.viewed_by_Handler_TimeStamp__c = System.now();                                                                   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggers aren't executed by viewing a record. They only occur when a record is created, edited, converted, deleted, merged, or recovered from the recycle bin. You could, however, write a Visualforce page to do something when the record is viewed, and place it on the page layout. Your page would be written like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" 
           extensions="CaseExtension" 
           action="{!updateCase}">
    <apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Case.OwnerId}" />
</apex:page>
```

The extension itself would look like this:

```
public class CaseExtension {
  ApexPages.StandardController c;
  public CaseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    c = controller;
  }
  public void updateCase() {
    Case caseRecord = (Case)c.getRecord();
    if(!caseRecord.viewed_by_Handler__c && UserInfo.getUserId() == caseRecord.OwnerId) {
      caseRecord.viewed_by_Handler__c = TRUE;
      caseRecord.viewed_by_Handler_TimeStamp__c = System.now();
      c.save();
    }
  }
}
```

To add it to the page layout, click on Setup > Customize > Cases > Page Layouts > Edit (Page Layout), and add the page to the layout. You can give it a zero height so it will not visibly display on the page.

Also, LastViewedDate is only accurate to the nearest second, while System.now() is accurate to the nearest millisecond, so all things being equal, you'd only have 0.1% chance of this code detecting the correct millisecond in which the record was viewed.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox ill try it and let you know if it works for me

Comment: I tried it but it still doesnt update the record, though it displays the ownerid of the user in the vfp

Comment: @sfdclearner - Then something is off in your conditions as it should work as written assuming your conditions are accurate

Comment: Thanks all! I got it working now. The problem was Im using a field that wasnt included in my query. Thanks again for the help